# Unable to import pypyodbc in pyenv

Tags: python, pypyodbc, pyscript

I made a python script that goes throught a sql serve gets presciption records then after cleaning up the data I query it based on two parameters, all of this works by itself but now I wanted to make this into a application that others can interact. So, I tried to make a py-script application.

**The problem:**

- When I  try to import the pypyodbc module which is what I use to access the sql server I get an error `ValueError: Couldn't find a pure Python 3 wheel for 'pypyodbc'. You can use 'micropip.install(..., keep_going=True)' to get a list of all packages with missing wheels`.
- To solve this I tried the micropip method and install a pure python library but was not able to.
  Here is the code:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />-->
  <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    
  </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <py-env>
            - pypyodbc
            - pandas
        </py-env>
        <div>Type an sample input here</div>
        <input type="text" id="test-input"/>
        <input type="text" id="test-input2"/>
        <button id="submit-button" type="submit" pys-onClick="my_function">OK</button>
        <p id="test-output"></p>
        <py-script>
            def my_function(*args, **kwargs):
                import pypyodbc

                import pandas as pd

                DRIVER_NAME='SQL SERVER'
                SERVER_NAME=''
                DATABASE_NAME=''

                text = Element('test-input').element.value
                text2=Element('test-input2').element.value
                connection_string=f""" 
                    DRIVER={{{DRIVER_NAME}}};
                    SERVER={SERVER_NAME};
                    DATABASE={DATABASE_NAME};
                    Trust_Connection=yes;
                    uid=;
                    pwd=;
                """
                conn = pypyodbc.connect(connection_string)

                sql_query="""
                SELECT * FROM Visit_Prescription
                """
                df_pres=pd.read_sql(sql_query,conn)



                DRIVER_NAME='SQL SERVER'
                SERVER_NAME=''
                DATABASE_NAME=''
                

                connection_string=f""" 
                    DRIVER={{{DRIVER_NAME}}};
                    SERVER={SERVER_NAME};
                    DATABASE={DATABASE_NAME};
                    Trust_Connection=yes;
                    uid=;
                    pwd=;
                """
                conn = pypyodbc.connect(connection_string)

                sql_query="""
                SELECT * FROM Visit_Diagnosis
                """
                df_Dia=pd.read_sql(sql_query,conn)

                df_pres=df_pres.drop(['drug_tradername','drug_form_package', 'scientific_code'], axis=1)

                df_pres=df_pres.groupby(['permanent_visit_no','patient_visit_registered_date_time'])['drug_package_information'].apply(','.join).reset_index()

                inner = pd.merge(left=df_Dia, right=df_pres, left_on='permanent_visit_no', right_on='permanent_visit_no')


                inner=inner.drop(['patient_visit_basic_details_serial_no','permanent_visit_no','patient_visit_registered_date_time_x','diagdate','patient_visit_registered_date_time_y'],axis=1)

                inner.drop_duplicates(inplace = True)

                inner=inner.drop(['icd_principal_secondary','icd_code_description'],axis=1)

                contain_values = inner[inner['icd_code'].str.contains('test-input')]
                contain_values=contain_values[contain_values['drug_package_information'].str.contains('test-input2')]
                pyscript.write('test-output',contain_values)
        </py-script>
</body>
</html>
```

So, I need help in trying to figure out a way to import the pypyodbc library or even a new library that can access the microsoft sql server. I am very new to this and with pyscript being relatively new I am unable to find much information online. So, any and all help is welcome and much appreciated.

Comment: Packages that use the Sockets API are not supported in the browser.

Comment: Oh alright thank you then I will figure another way to do this